# How to get a floating point result from dividing two integers

Tags: java

I can't get float value from int/int.

```
float rs;
int a=10;
int b=3;
rs=(float)a/b;
```

Result : 3.0 .
I need 3.333
Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing your code, it does indeed give `3.333`, because the typecast takes precedence... did you execute some other code?

---

Another possible option is to typecast `b`.

```
rs = a / (float)b;
```

You could also typecast `a`, but you'd need an extra set of parenthesis.

Here's an [`ideone`](http://ideone.com/y6i6Vt) demo.

Comment: Downvoter, comment please?

Comment: @Oleg THANK YOU for replying. I can respect your frankness. I've addressed the problem. Hopefully that's better now. Cheers (remove your down vote if you're feeling charitable).

Comment: np, I even upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: The cast has priority:

```
rs = (float) a / b;
```

Or,

```
float new_a = a;
rs = new_a / b;
```

Comment: I can't change my upvote by after checking, this is wrong. The cast already has priority.

Comment: @Oleg Go ahead.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks!